# ViewPager and Fragments: How can I know when a fragment is not visible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm developing an Android 3.1 Tablet application using android.support.v4.

I want to know if there is an event which is fired when user swipe from one fragment to another one.

Is there an event fired when a fragment is hide by another one?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if there is an event which is fired when user swipe
>   from one fragment to another one.
>
> Is there an event fired when a fragment is hide by another one?

I think what you're looking for is the [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html). You just have to set that listener for your `ViewPager` to listen for specific events.

From that interface the [`onPageSelected`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected%28int%29) will tell you(with the `int` parameter) which page has become the visible one so you know you know which fragment is visible or not.

The [`onPageScrolled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrolled%28int,%20float,%20int%29) will tell you when the user starts to play with the `ViewPager`'s content.